How do i fix "SCRIPT ERROR: No such export getSharedObject in resource es_extended " error in fivem?
I am new to fivem and i am trying to make a server please be kind i cannot seem to fix this error after adding a new script to my server.
I seen on youtube they try fixing it by opening the client.lua but i cannot access this [enter image description here][1]certain scripts client.lua bc of the formatting?
link to image
https://i.sstatic.net/bZj7VjDU.png

Please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?

Change it with ESX = exports["es_extended"]:getSharedObject()   as the esx:getSharedObject export is now deprecated, also the new version helps a lot with modders.
